# hide() / show() not working after ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: '/test/',
  data: data,

  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", Cookies.get('csrftoken'));
  },
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function name(resp) {
    // this part is not working
    $('#steps-uid-0-p-0').show();
    $('#steps-uid-0-p-1').hide();
  }
});
```

I am unable to show and hide a div, if the response from ajax is an error. It works well in the console. I have tried using `setTimeout()` but is there any other solution?

Comment: Try using delay: show().delay(number).hide() (number in miliseconds)

Comment: Wait .. Are you trying to show a div and hide another div? ''#steps-uid-0-p-0'' and ''#steps-uid-0-p-1'

Comment: yes, I want to show div with this id 'steps-uid-0-p-0' and hide div having this id 'steps-uid-0-p-1'

Comment: What exactly happens? Does the hide method work for this div? and the show method, is it working? Console displays an error? Are these divs being created just before the ajax call? please describe better

Comment: show() and hide() put in success function

Comment: @ParasRaiyani No, I want in error function.

Comment: @AksJacoves hide and show did not work, in the console, same code works well.

Comment: You are hiding in error callback proabably no error happened?

Comment: Yes, error occurs. I have tried using console.log() inside error fn.

Comment: Make sure the ajax call gives an error, perhaps you are not getting any error.
Also make sure the div with id `steps-uid-0-p-0` is not a child of `steps-uid-0-p-1`.

Comment: @AdeelTahir, Yes ajax call gives an error. div having ids are different, not child of any of them

Comment: @SarojRai it is so weird, i have run your ajax call and on error it is executing that block and hiding one of the div.Can you try hiding / showing those div with `document.getElementById`

Comment: Are you using `visibility` CSS property to hide/show them initially?  `.show()` and `.hide()` manipulate the `display` property; if your elements use `visibility`, or `!important`, they won't work.  [Here's an example in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/67wu9raz/).